# Azure Functions binding redirect

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, assembly-binding-redirect, azure-functions-runtime

Is it possible to include a web.config or app.config file in the azure functions folder structure to allow assembly binding redirects?

Answer (score 33):

Assuming you are using the latest (June'17) Visual Studio 2017 Function Tooling, I derived a somewhat-reasonable config-based solution for this following a snippet of code posted by `npiasecki` over on [Issue #992](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/992#issuecomment-298624059).

It would be ideal if this were managed through the framework, but at least being configuration-driven you have a bit more change isolation. I suppose you could also use some pre-build steps or T4 templating that reconciles the versions of the nugets in the project (and their dependencies) before writing out this config or generating code.

##### **So the downside..**

.. becomes having to remember to update the `BindingRedirects` config when you update the NuGet package (*this is often a problem in app.configs anyway*). You may also have an issue with the config-driven solution if you need to redirect `Newtonsoft`.

In our case, we were using the new Azure Fluent NuGet that had a dependency on an older version of `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` than the version of the normal ARM management libraries which are used side-by-side in a particular Function.

##### ***local.settings.json***

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "BindingRedirects": "[ { \"ShortName\": \"Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory\", \"RedirectToVersion\": \"3.13.9.1126\", \"PublicKeyToken\": \"31bf3856ad364e35\" } ]"
    }
}
```

##### ***FunctionUtilities.cs***

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Utilities.AzureFunctions
{
    public static class FunctionUtilities
        {
            public class BindingRedirect
            {
                public string ShortName { get; set; }
                public string PublicKeyToken { get; set; }
                public string RedirectToVersion { get; set; }
            }
            
            public static void ConfigureBindingRedirects()
            {
                var config = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BindingRedirects");
                var redirects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BindingRedirect>>(config);
                redirects.ForEach(RedirectAssembly);
            }

            public static void RedirectAssembly(BindingRedirect bindingRedirect)
            {
                ResolveEventHandler handler = null;

                handler = (sender, args) =>
                {
                    var requestedAssembly = new AssemblyName(args.Name);

                    if (requestedAssembly.Name != bindingRedirect.ShortName)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }

                    var targetPublicKeyToken = new AssemblyName("x, PublicKeyToken=" + bindingRedirect.PublicKeyToken)
                        .GetPublicKeyToken();
                    requestedAssembly.Version = new Version(bindingRedirect.RedirectToVersion);
                    requestedAssembly.SetPublicKeyToken(targetPublicKeyToken);
                    requestedAssembly.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= handler;

                    return Assembly.Load(requestedAssembly);
                };

                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += handler;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This is pretty much necessary for most nuget projects. Hoping they'll address this soon.

Comment: For anyone struggling making this work: If you have more than 1 version that needs to be rebound, you'll have to remove the line AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= handler;

As this meant only the first version it found was redirected.

Comment: What is the issue with redirecting Newtonsoft?

Comment: @NicholasJ.Markkula The issue in this example stems from the fact that the code to determine what to redirect is utilizing Newtonsoft. So if the calling code's AppDomain has loaded version 9.x of Newtonsoft, but then the json file wants to redirect to 10.x, that won't work because 9.x is already loaded in the AppDomain and thus can't be redirected on first load.

Comment: We implemented this.  It works on my machine, but on another person's machine, he's getting a StackOverflowException.  Microsoft says you [should not call Assembly.Load from your handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/resolve-loads#what-the-event-handler-should-not-do) because it can lead to a stack overflow.  Is there any alternative to that?

Comment: @NathanX I think that's going to be difficult to diagnose in the comments; it may warrant its own question to fully explore the specific application + configuration concerns you have going on. Also this is pretty old and there may be better solutions that asking a new question may better-surface.

Comment: @JoeBrockhaus How do you solve this then when you have two versions of the assembly? I can see in the answer the the event is unsubscribed and I'm using the same solution but it works only for 1 version and throws error for second version. :(

Answer (score 24):

Just posted a new blog post explaining how to fix the problem, have a look:

https://codopia.wordpress.com/2017/07/21/how-to-fix-the-assembly-binding-redirect-problem-in-azure-functions/

It's actually a tweaked version of the JoeBrockhaus's code, that works well even for Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Comment: This does not appear to resolve it for deserialization of objects using DocumentDB data bindings though...  The databinding's attempted to deserialize is called prior to the redirect logic being called somehow.

Comment: true. Had the same issue with the queue triggers, the fix is to make the trigger's datatype "String" and deserialize it yourself in the code after setting the binding redirect.

Comment: Based on akazemis's blog, I added some protection against failure since this code is ran very early, its hard to anaylse exceptions. In Startup
`
 try
                        {
                            AssemblyBindingRedirectHelper.ConfigureBindingRedirects();
                            IsStarted = true;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            StartError = ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace;
                        }`
With StartError being stored staticaly
Then, at the

Answer (score 11):

Inspired by the accepted answer I figured I'd do a more generic one which takes into account upgrades as well.

It fetches all assemblies, orders them descending to get the newest version on top, then returns the newest version on resolve. I call this in a static constructor myself.

```
public static void RedirectAssembly()
{
    var list = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Select(a => a.GetName())
        .OrderByDescending(a => a.Name)
        .ThenByDescending(a => a.Version)
        .Select(a => a.FullName)
        .ToList();
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
    {
        var requestedAssembly = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
        foreach (string asmName in list)
        {
            if (asmName.StartsWith(requestedAssembly.Name + ","))
            {
                return Assembly.Load(asmName);
            }
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

Comment: OrderByDescending(a => a.FullName) might have issues comparing 9.0.0 version with 10.0.0 version.

Comment: Thank you @wz366. I edited my code to sort properly on version number,

Answer (score 3):

It is not directly possible today, but we are thinking about ways to achieve this. Can you please open an issue on https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues to make sure your specific scenario is looked at? Thanks!

Comment: new related issue: Provide Binding redirects for CSX loading multiple dll #1239 https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1239

Answer (score 2):

First SO post, so apologies if formatting's a bit off.

We've hit this issue a couple of times and managed to find a better way of getting the required redirects by forcing MSBUILD to generate a binding redirects file and then parsing that to be used with the previously suggested answer.

Modify the project settings and add in a couple of targets:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>True</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

These classes apply the binding redirects using the same idea that was posted earlier ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44425580)) except instead of using the host.json file it reads from the generated binding redirects file. The filename to use is from reflection using the ExecutingAssembly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

 public static class AssemblyBindingRedirectHelper
    {
        private static FunctionRedirectBindings _redirects;

        public static void ConfigureBindingRedirects()
        {
            // Only load the binding redirects once
            if (_redirects != null)
                return;

            _redirects = new FunctionRedirectBindings();

            foreach (var redirect in _redirects.BindingRedirects)
            {
                RedirectAssembly(redirect);
            }
        }

        public static void RedirectAssembly(BindingRedirect bindingRedirect)
        {
            ResolveEventHandler handler = null;

            handler = (sender, args) =>
            {
                var requestedAssembly = new AssemblyName(args.Name);

                if (requestedAssembly.Name != bindingRedirect.ShortName)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                var targetPublicKeyToken = new AssemblyName("x, PublicKeyToken=" + bindingRedirect.PublicKeyToken).GetPublicKeyToken();
                requestedAssembly.Version = new Version(bindingRedirect.RedirectToVersion);
                requestedAssembly.SetPublicKeyToken(targetPublicKeyToken);
                requestedAssembly.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= handler;

                return Assembly.Load(requestedAssembly);
            };

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += handler;
        }
    }

    public class FunctionRedirectBindings
    {
        public HashSet<BindingRedirect> BindingRedirects { get; } = new HashSet<BindingRedirect>();

        public FunctionRedirectBindings()
        {
            var assm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var bindingRedirectFileName = $"{assm.GetName().Name}.dll.config";
            var dir = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME"), @"site\wwwroot");
            var fullPath = Path.Combine(dir, bindingRedirectFileName);

            if(!File.Exists(fullPath))
                throw new ArgumentException($"Could not find binding redirect file. Path:{fullPath}");

            var xml = ReadFile<configuration>(fullPath);
            TransformData(xml);
        }

        private T ReadFile<T>(string path)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                var obj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                reader.Close();
                return obj;
            }
        }

        private void TransformData(configuration xml)
        {
            foreach(var item in xml.runtime)
            {
                var br = new BindingRedirect
                {
                    ShortName = item.dependentAssembly.assemblyIdentity.name,
                    PublicKeyToken = item.dependentAssembly.assemblyIdentity.publicKeyToken,
                    RedirectToVersion = item.dependentAssembly.bindingRedirect.newVersion
                };
                BindingRedirects.Add(br);
            }
        }
    }

    public class BindingRedirect
    {
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
        public string PublicKeyToken { get; set; }
        public string RedirectToVersion { get; set; }
    }
```

Xml classes to use to deserialise the generated binding redirect file into something easier to use. These were generated from the binding redirects file by using VS2017 "paste special -> paste xml as classes" so feel free to roll your own if needed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

// NOTE: Generated code may require at least .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET Core/Standard 2.0.
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class configuration
{

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("assemblyBinding", Namespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1", IsNullable = false)]
    public assemblyBinding[] runtime { get; set; }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class assemblyBinding
{

    public assemblyBindingDependentAssembly dependentAssembly { get; set; }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1")]
public partial class assemblyBindingDependentAssembly
{

    public assemblyBindingDependentAssemblyAssemblyIdentity assemblyIdentity { get; set; }

    public assemblyBindingDependentAssemblyBindingRedirect bindingRedirect { get; set; }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1")]
public partial class assemblyBindingDependentAssemblyAssemblyIdentity
{

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string publicKeyToken { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string culture { get; set; }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1")]
public partial class assemblyBindingDependentAssemblyBindingRedirect
{

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string oldVersion { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string newVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate solution for when you want the exact version of a particular assembly.  With this code, you can easily deploy the assemblies that are missing:

```
public static class AssemblyHelper
{
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>
    /// Redirection hack because Azure functions don't support it.
    /// How to use:  
    ///     If you get an error that a certain version of a dll can't be found:
    ///         1) deploy that particular dll in any project subfolder 
    ///         2) In your azure function static constructor, Call 
    ///             AssemblyHelper.IncludeSupplementalDllsWhenBinding()
    ///         
    /// This will hook the binding calls and look for a matching dll anywhere 
    /// in the $HOME folder tree.  
    /// </summary>
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static void IncludeSupplementalDllsWhenBinding()
    {
        var searching = false;

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // This prevents a stack overflow
            if(searching) return null;
            var requestedAssembly = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
            searching = true;

            Assembly foundAssembly = null;
            try
            {
                foundAssembly = Assembly.Load(requestedAssembly);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Could not load assembly: {args.Name} because {e.Message}");
            }

            searching  = false;

            if(foundAssembly == null)
            {
                var home = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME") ?? ".";

                var possibleFiles = Directory.GetFiles(home, requestedAssembly.Name + ".dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                foreach (var file in possibleFiles)
                {
                    var possibleAssembly = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(file);
                    if (possibleAssembly.Version == requestedAssembly.Version)
                    {
                        foundAssembly = Assembly.Load(possibleAssembly);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return foundAssembly;
        };
    }
}
```