# The type or namespace name 'Bot' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'?

Tags: c#, azure, bots, csx

Are other people having as much trouble with the Bot framework as I am?

I'm just trying to follow the steps in [Debug an Azure Bot Service bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/azure/azure-bot-service-debug-bot) so that I can edit and run my code locally and then push it up to the cloud.  After a long struggle, I run the 'debughost.cmd' file and I get told that it's not able to resolve 'Bot'!

the exact error is

> D:\projects\PROJECT\messages\EchoDialog.csx(3,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Bot' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> D:\projects\HelpfulCoa\messages\EchoDialog.csx(4,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Bot' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> run.csx(9,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Bot' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> run.csx(10,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Bot' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The code is just the Echo sample, and I'm doing my best to just follow the myriad of fragile steps in the docs.

Any else run into this?  Is there a solution?

Comment: The solution, apparently, was keep on diking with NuGet and the services and ding builds, and asking to update stuff.  Eventually, whatever was wrong is magically fixed.

Comment: Nope, I was wrong.  The solution is to abandon the Azure bot builder with functions, and instead use the .NET version (one is hosted as "functions" and the other is hosted as an ordinary ASP.NET website)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the Function Bot service.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/992

[azure functions with nuget packages that have different versions of the same dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40816285/azure-functions-with-nuget-packages-that-have-different-versions-of-the-same-dep#)

Comment: I literally downloaded it from Microsoft and put in Microsoft Visual Studio and the first thing i read from above is, "This is a known limitation and, with the current design, not something that can be easily addressed."  My God what is going on!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the .net framework version to >=4.6. This error comes when the .net framework is 4.5. Microsoft.Bot.Builder version 3.8.0 works with it.