# bindingRedirect for Azure Function using EF Core 2

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-functions

Targeting Framework 4.6.1 and creating an Azure Function using VS2017 which uses EF Core 2. I'm getting the error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.ValueTuple, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies.

...which I normally solve with a bindingRedirect in the app.config file. Since Azure Functions don't use app.config, is there a way to solve this? Do I need to use EF 6 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are loaded into the same process as Azure Functions, so you only have access to the same version of the assemblies that the runtime pre-loads.

This is a [know issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1239) and there is work being done on it. I believe they are working on some kind of "language service" where we'll have complete control over what assemblies are loaded.

Until then, there are some work-arounds:
[Azure Functions binding redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093972/azure-functions-binding-redirect)

Comment: Am I correct that this is an EF Core 2.0 issue and that moving back to EF 6 would fix it? Or would targeting a newer framework fix this?

Comment: A nice walk through of the binding redirect workaround here: https://codopia.wordpress.com/2017/07/21/how-to-fix-the-assembly-binding-redirect-problem-in-azure-functions/