# Azure Function V2 with Entity Framework 6.2

Tags: .net, azure, entity-framework-6, azure-functions

I'm trying to use Azure Function in my solution while all my other projects in the solution are using Entity Framework 6.2.

Now the problem is I can't use Azure Function V1 because it requires Newtonsoft.json 9.0.1 and **NOT** above. All my other projects have version 12 and I can't downgrade because they have dependencies to other nugget packages.

My only option is Azure Function V2, **BUT** the Azure Function V2 doesn't work properly with configuration manager and EF needs that and I can't turn it off in EF.

So it looks like I'm stuck with Webjobs since it looks impossible to use Azure Function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't 
[Azure function v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions) will support only .net core. Which means to make it work you need to update to Entityframework Core

But to solve your  v1 problem you can use Assembly binding redirect its dirty hack but it works [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093972/azure-functions-binding-redirect)