# Unable to load assembly or dll System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0 in Azure function

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, runtime, azure-functions, assembly-binding-redirect

I have one Web API application,Added `System.buffer reference 4.0.3.0.`

When we call this project from another project from the same solution it's working fine.

But when I refer to this project reference in Azure function - It's throwing following error.

[image]

[image]

I have tried to make changes by changing versions but no luck.

In Azure function, we are just referencing project.

```
<TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
```

Comment: is your solution and function both using same runtime i.e. .net framework or .net core ?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Functions 1.x Runtime does not support binding redirects ([github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/992)).

I ended up writing code to apply the binding redirects myself, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44425580/310446).