# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=2.12.1.36699, Culture=neutral or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, azure, nuget, appinsights

My application has a nuget package called `CustomLogger`(created by us). CustomLogger has `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` nuget package installed in it with version `2.12.1`

[image]

Today I installed another nuget package called `HistoryStats`(created by us) which also has `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` nuget package installed in it but with newer version `2.14.0`

[image]

After installing the second nuget, my application is failing with below error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights,
> Version=2.12.1.36699, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified

Here is my reference in .csproj file

```
<PackageReference Include="CustomLogger" Version="2020.2.19.3" />
<PackageReference Include="HistoryStats" Version="2020.4.27.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.30" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob" Version="11.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common" Version="11.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.1" />
```

Is there a way to refer different `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` version for different nuget package ?

Comment: What type of application is it? In WPF in the app.config you can use assemblyRedirect to point all references to one version, but I have not used these on other project types.

Comment: @RyanThomas - Its a Azure function App, there is no `app.config` file.

Comment: Ah okay. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093972/azure-functions-binding-redirect

Answer (score 0):

For a WPF application in the app.config under the "runtime" element you can add an assembly redirect accordingly. Example below, you will need to change the numbers to suit.

I am not used these on other project types, but imagine the process is similar.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.12.1.36699" newVersion="2.12.1.36699" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

For Azure Functions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093972/azure-functions-binding-redirect) question may help.